# How do I import email in Wanderlust?

Tags: email, wanderlust, imap

I am setting up Wanderlust, and have an older "Maildir" folder created by Offlineimap. Am wondering how I can import these emails in Wanderlust and/or combine this folder with my new WL folder?

Can I just move the files in each subdir?

Comment: Wanderlust supports IMAP and Maildir, but they are in different folders on the computer.  You can set up your `.folders` file to have both.  I do this for 3 things:  (1) my on-line IMAP folders, (2) my backup to the hard drive created with offlineimap, and (3) the duplicate of what is inside the cyberspace IMAP folders on the shared server that I sync to my hard drive with rsync.  Please clarify what is meant by *combine* and *import* as it relates to this question.

Comment: In addition to customizing the `.folders` configuration file to point to your `Maildir` folders, see also the variable `elmo-maildir-folder-path`.  For example, I set this path to a location of my choosing, and then set up additional subfolders within that main directory.  My subfolders include, but are not limited to:  my `offlineimap` kitten caboodle, my `rsync`-ed IMAP folders from the shared server in cyberspace, a special folder where I can manually put any email that floats my boat, etc ...

Comment: Clarify combine & import: currently I have (among other things) "old" emails in a Maildir folder on my hard drive, and "new" emails in another WL Maildir folder also on my hard drive. I want to do an operation so that I have one single WL Maildir folder containing all those emails.

Comment: But is it better to change so that `.folders` contain both?

Comment: `Maildir` stuff is just files and folders on the hard drive.  You can manually add/remove emails from one location to the other.  If you want to play with marking and moving emails within Wanderlust, have a look at the function `wl-summary-refile` -- there may be some others.  You can mark a region of emails and then act upon them in bulk.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought maybe there might be a risk that the same filenames could occur in both folders.

Answer (score 1):

First, add your folder to Wanderlust: in the Folders buffer, say:

```
m a .~/path/to/folder
```

Then switch to the folder, and mark the whole summary buffer:

```
M-< C-SPC M->
```

Mark all the messages for copying into the destination folder:

```
r O %INBOX
```

and execute the copy:

```
x
```